# How do I make this regular expression more general?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.8.7

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7. I have a text file with following content:

```
"testhost-01.test.de|lan|ip-v4|cmk-agent|tcp|ip-v4-only|site:tir_projects|test|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
"testhost-02.test.de|lan|ip-v4|cmk-agent|tcp|ip-v4-only|site:tir_projects|prod|puppetagent|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
"testhost-03.test.de|wan|ip-v4|cmk-agent|tcp|ip-v4-only|site:tir_projects|prod|puppetagent|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
"testhost-04.test.de|ip-v4|cmk-agent|tcp|ip-v4-only|site:tir_projects|dmz|prod|puppetagent|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
"testhost-05.test.de|wan|ip-v4|cmk-agent|tcp|ip-v4-only|site:tir_projects|prod|puppetagent|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
"testhost-06.test.de|lan|ip-v4|cmk-agent|tcp|ip-v4-only|site:tir_projects|prod|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
"testhost-07.test.de|ip-v6|cmk-agent|tcp|site:tir_projects|ip-v6-only|dmz|prod|puppetagent|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
"testhost-08.test.de|ip-v4|snmp|snmp-only|ip-v4-only|critical|site:tir_projects|dmz|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
```

I'm trying to extract the hostnames (`testhost-01.test.de` - `testhost-08.test.de`) to an Array but only when `"puppetagent"` is in the same line.

The result should be:

```
[
  "testhost-02.test.de",
  "testhost-03.test.de",
  "testhost-04.test.de",
  "testhost-05.test.de",
  "testhost-07.test.de"
]
```

Code Example:

```
path = "Textfile"
file = IO.read(path)
nodes = file.scan(/^"(.*)\|lan.*\|puppetagent/).flatten
```

This example above works only for lines where after the first pipe,
"lan" follows, so it only finds host `02`.

Comment: many many thanks Kristján. It works very good.

Comment: I'd highly recommend moving from Ruby 1.8.7 ASAP. It's extremely out of date; Continuing to use it will only cause problems. Look at RVM and rbenv for how to manage multiple versions of Ruby on a system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to restrict output to lines that include `|lan`, you can't include `|lan` in the expression. It looks like you want `|lan` to mark the end of your capture group - instead, you can restrict your capture group to not include `|` by using the character set `[^|]`. Then, even if the line doesn't include `lan`, you'll stop at the first `|`. After the `|`, you don't care about content until `puppetagent`, so we'll consume that with `.*`.

```
/^"([^|]*).*puppetagent/
```

In plain English, that's

- `^"` Start with `"`
- `([^|]*)` Capture anything that's not a `|`
- `.*` Accept anything else on the line
- `puppetagent` Require `puppetagent` to be present